# How to give days of a week number value

Tags: python

I have a task to give each day of the week a number value. For example if the day is one the program will return monday. Everything i have right now works except for sunday aka day 7. I tried rearranging code but nothing works.

```
def dayOfWeek(day): 
    if day not in range(1, 7):
        return "Unknown"
    elif day == 1:
        return "Monday"
    elif day == 2:
        return "Tuesday"
    elif day == 3:
        return "Wednesday"
    elif day == 4:
        return "Thursday"
    elif day == 5:
        return "Friday"
    elif day == 6:
        return "Saturday"
    elif day == 7:
        return "Sunday"


assert (dayOfWeek(0) == "Unknown")
assert (dayOfWeek(7) == "Sunday")
assert (dayOfWeek(1) == "Monday")
assert (dayOfWeek(3) == "Wednesday"
```

)

Comment: The range function is exclusive (ex: range(m, n) allows all the numbers from m to n-1)

Comment: If you want range 1 to 7, you'll need to do range(1,8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dayOfWeek(day): 
    if day not in range(1, 8):
        return "Unknown"
    elif day == 1:
        return "Monday"
    elif day == 2:
        return "Tuesday"
    elif day == 3:
        return "Wednesday"
    elif day == 4:
        return "Thursday"
    elif day == 5:
        return "Friday"
    elif day == 6:
        return "Saturday"
    elif day == 7:
        return "Sunday"


assert (dayOfWeek(0) == "Unknown")
assert (dayOfWeek(7) == "Sunday")
assert (dayOfWeek(1) == "Monday")
assert (dayOfWeek(3) == "Wednesday")
```

Use a range of 1 to 8 because python cuts off the last number.

Answer (score 2):

This is only offered as a future alternative. Functionally there is no difference.

You could also set a dictionary of the values

```
def dayOfWeek(day):
        days = {
            1: 'Monday',
            2: 'Tuesday',
            3: 'Wednesday',
            4: 'Thursday',
            5: 'Friday',
            6: 'Saturday',
            7: 'Sunday'
        }

        return days[day] if day in days else 'Unknown'
```

Answer (score 0):

In range function, python leaves the last number i.e if it is range(a,b) then the range goes from a to b-1. So your correct range will be (1,8) as said by Vedant Mehta. If you're confused with range, then use `else` statement. Your code:

```
def dayOfWeek(day): 
    if day == 1:
        return "Monday"
    elif day == 2:
        return "Tuesday"
    elif day == 3:
        return "Wednesday"
    elif day == 4:
        return "Thursday"
    elif day == 5:
        return "Friday"
    elif day == 6:
        return "Saturday"
    elif day == 7:
        return "Sunday"
    else:
        return "Unknown"


assert (dayOfWeek(0) == "Unknown")
assert (dayOfWeek(7) == "Sunday")
assert (dayOfWeek(1) == "Monday")
assert (dayOfWeek(3) == "Wednesday")
```